# How can I split a string with "--------------------" in C#?

Tags: c#, arrays, string, split

i have a string like this:

```
string x = "Hello, my- name
--------------------
is Philip J. Fry
--------------------
and i like cartoons";
```

I have to split the string x with character sequence `--------------------` (all 20 `-`, not only one) and I would like to have a result like this:

```
result = {"Hello, my- name", "is Philip J. Fry", "and i like cartoons"}
```

I tried x.Split("--------------------"), but Visual Studio says that it' an error.
Thank you for your help.

Comment: No, because sometimes I have only one "-" char and I want to split only if "--------------------" occurs. If i write x.Split("--------------------") Visual Studio says that it is and error.

Comment: Yes it is an error because if you want to pass, as the first parameter of String.Split a string then you need the overload that takes an array of strings and also a second parameter, the StringSplitOptions. Check the documentation about string.Split. _x.Split(new string[] {"-----------"},StringSplitOptions.None);_ and also the duplicate

Comment: Try `Regex.Split` instead since you can specify a string instead of just a collection of characters.

Comment: I understand, but the problem is that sometimes i can have only one "-", so I don't want to split. I want to split only if I have "--------------------". How is it possible?

Comment: Thank you Lasse, you resolve my problem!

Comment: @NicolaT what is wrong with _x.Split(new string[] {"--------------------"},StringSplitOptions.None);_